# Devise, rails) How to appear error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, alert, error-messages-for

I purely set up the sign-up page using gem:

controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      unless user_signed_in?
         redirect_to "/users/sign_in"
      end
   end
end
```

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

However, the error message doesn't show up whenever I use invaild username or password. The page remains same and nothing happens.
What I need to show up error message? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a view just set up after the form tag `#devise_error_messages!` method:

**edit.html.slim**:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
```

Comment: in divse/registration/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name,url:registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
 <%= devise_error_messages! %> alredy exist. Should I change something else? I don't have anything under view yet though.

Comment: @AileenHwang no, it should show all the errors belong to devise